# Can I refer to the primary key of any entity in JPQL by the name "id", regardless of the entity's ID property name?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, jpql, jpa-2.0

Hibernate allows you to just say ".id".  Let's say I have:

```
@Entity public class Customer {
  @Id private Integer customerId;
  @Basic private String customerName;
  // getters and setters
}
```

And I want to get the name of a customer by ID:

```
SELECT cust.customerName FROM Customer cust WHERE cust.id = :customerId
```

Notice I put "id" rather than "customerId", as a shortcut.  Is this valid JPQL, or is it only valid in Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA specification doesn't define such a shortcut, access to state fields (including an `Id` property) is by name:

> #### 4.3 Abstract Schema Types and Query Domains
>
> (...)
>
> Informally, the abstract schema type
>   of an entity can be characterized as
>   follows:
>
> - For every persistent field
>     or get accessor method (for a
>     persistent property) of the entity
>     class, there is a field
>     (“state-field”) whose abstract schema
>     type corresponds to that of the field
>     or the result type of the accessor
>     method.
> - For every persistent
>     relationship field or get accessor
>     method (for a persistent relationship
>     property) of the entity class, there
>     is a field (“association-field”) whose
>     type is the abstract schema type of
>     the related entity (or, if the
>     relationship is a one-to-many or
>     many-to-many, a collection of such).
>
> (...)

In other words, this is Hibernate specific (see section [14.5. Referring to identifier property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-identifier-property)) so don't rely on this if you want to write JPQL.

---

This is what you'd get with EclipseLink for example (`MyEntity` doesn't have an `id` field):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [select e from MyEntity e where e.id = :id], line 1, column 33: unknown state or association field [id] of class [com.acme.MyEntity].
```